# save method or post_save signal is not being called while through model instance of a ManyToManyField is getting created

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have a `Post` model in my Django app. It has a many-to-many relationship with `User` model through the `UserTag` model named `user_tags`.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    user_tags = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=UserTag)
```

```py
class UserTag(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        print("#### user tagged ##### - save method")
        print(self.user)

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

@receiver(post_save, sender=UserTag)
def user_tagged_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if not created:
        return
    
    print("#### user tagged ##### - post save signal")
    print(instance.user)
```

When I tag a user to a post as follows:

```py
post.user_tags.set(users)
```

or

```py
post.user_tags.add(user)
```

`UserTang` model instance gets created but `save` method or `post_save` signal of the `UserTag` model is not getting called.

I want to send notification to the user and remove the notification depending on the creation and deletion of the `UserTag` instance.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or can you suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`RelatedManager.add` does not call the save method of the through model. Neither does `set` (it uses `add` under the hood). Instead these methods use `QuerySet.bulk_create` which directly inserts into the table.

> Using add() with a many-to-many relationship, however, will not call any
> save() methods (the bulk argument doesn’t exist), but rather create the relationships using QuerySet.bulk_create(). **If you need to execute some custom logic when a relationship is created, listen to the m2m_changed signal, which will trigger pre_add and post_add actions**.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add